# Github error: Repository under migration

Tags: git, repository, version-control, github

There are two accounts on github I'd like to use. The first, my private one, is working correctly, I'm able to set up new repositorys, clone and push as I like.

Then I signed up with a second user two days ago. It is meant to be my 'official' working account. So I try to set up some repositorys from this user. It seems to work, but all I get - instead of the usual set up instructions etc is:

> **Repository under migration.**
>
> The route for your user could not be
>   found. Usually this means that your
>   repositories are being migrated to a
>   new storage server to better serve
>   you. Your repository should be
>   available again very soon.

I tried forking another project too, but all I get is the same 'error' message.

Working: [xijo/reverse-markdown](http://github.com/xijo/reverse-markdown)

Still not working: [echo-on-waves/test](http://github.com/echo-on-waves/test)

Anyone know how long this will last or what I'm doing wrong? I can't figure out the problem which makes setting up repositorys on two similar users working in different ways..

Thank you for your help! ;)

Joe

Comment: please start a ticket at http://support.github.com thanks!
scott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be because Github just recently moved their hosting to Rackspace from EngineYard. You can find more information at the blog, [this post](http://github.com/blog/500-state-of-the-hub-rackspace-day-0) goes over the state of the site after the move. Some things are broken as of now, but they are working on getting everything fixed.